# Given a number N how many pairs of numbers have square sum less than or equal to N?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, combinations

Let's define *F(N)* as the number of pairs of distinct positive integers *(A,B)* such that *A<sup>2</sup>+B<sup>2</sup>≤N* and *A<B*.

If *N=5* the only possible such pair is *(1,2)* for *N=10* the pairs are two:  *(1,2)* and *(1,3)*.

Furthermore we have *F(13)=3*, *F(17)=4*, *F(17)=4*, *F(20)=5*, *F(20)=5*, *F(25)=6*, *F(100)=31* and so on for every number which is sum of two distinct non-zero squares.

So far I have the following solution:

```
long long SOLVE(lld n)
{
    long long x=sqrt(n),up=0;
    long long a=x,b=1;
    while(abs(a-(b-1))!=1)
    {

        while(sqr(a)+sqr(b)<=n )
        {
            b++;
        }
        up+=(b-1);
        a--;
    }
    b--;
    up+=(b*(b+1))/2;
    return up;
}
int main()
{
      cout<<number(100);
return 0;
}
```

Same numbers are not countable, thus *(1,1)* and *(2,2)* are invalid tuples.
Same combination but different order counts only once. Thus *(1,2)* and *(2,1)* count only as once.

But as the range of *N* is 1, I need a more efficient algorithm or formula to calculate this. Is there any trick to make my code more efficient?

Comment: Does *A* have to be smaller than *B*? Otherwise the tuples *(2,1)* and *(3,1)* could count as well.

Comment: No (1,2) and (2,1) both counts only once .

Comment: Furthermore what is `lld`? I'm a bit familiar with C++, but don't know what type this is.

Comment: lld= long long int . I use a macro to define this .

Comment: `sqrt` thus does a "floor" operation before storing it into a variable?

Comment: Yeah . It counts floor . Such as sqrt(8) = 2 .

Comment: Is this a Project Euler question? I remember once seeing a similar question during the Benelux Algorithm Programming Contest (BAPC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pseudocode:

```
int count=0;
for (smaller=1; ;++smaller)
{
    maxlarger = floor(sqrt(N-smaller*smaller));
    if (maxlarger <= smaller)
        break;
    count+=(maxlarger-smaller);
}
return count;
```

Comment: Doesn't work . It Gives wrong output . F(5)=1 , But your programme gives F(5)=2. F(100)=31 but your programme gives F(100)=38 .

Comment: you don't want (1,1) and (1,2) for F(5)?  Oh, you want both numbers distinct.  no problem. edited

Comment: No , Sorry , i forgot to mention , Same numbers are not countable . .

Comment: Thanks mate . Worked fine !

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to calculate the number of *B*'s: you can simply calculate the largest B for which this is possible, which is immediately the number of tuples for that *A*:

*B<sub>max</sub>=sqrt(N-A<sup>2</sup>)*, and the lower-bound on *B* is:
*B<sub>min</sub>=A+1*.

Now you can do the following:

- iterate for *A* from *1* to *sqrt(n)*;
- for each such *A* calculate the amount of *B*'s you can use;
- calculate the sum of these.

So this leads us to the following algorithm:

```
lld SOLVE(lld n) {
    lld aM=sqrt(n);
    lld a=1;
    lld res = 0;
    for(lld a = 1; a < aM; a++) {
        int nB = sqrt(n-a*a)-a;
        if(nB > 0) {
            res += nB;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

from the moment, no more *B* values can be found, one can break off the search.

I've written a [demo](http://cpp.sh/5muhc) here which seems to work.

Comment: why do we iterate for A from 1 to sqrt(n)?